# jQuery append not working from within a plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, append

I want to run a an append(and more stuff later on) from within a plugin, but for some reason it doesn't do anything.

the code(basic):

```
(function($){   

    function _init(){

        $('body').append('<div class="msg"/>');

    }

    _init()             

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Are you initializing this plugin correctly?

Comment: This is not really a plugin. It is the same as just defining and  calling `_init()` immediately. Most likely `document.body` is not loaded yet at this point. It is not clear to me at which stage you want to execute which code.

Comment: This is a plugin but its not initialized at this stage, but i see that its because the DOM isn't ready.......stupid me :P

Comment: I mixed up a little. This isn't a jQuery plugin. My bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it in code, it should look like:

```
(function($){

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        $('body').append('<div class="msg"/>');

    });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 4):

jQuery append can only work after dom ready. The code you have pasted is probably working before dom ready event. Please check below;

http://api.jquery.com/ready/